# VBA Code to place the name and path of the selected database in a textbox and output in a listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have been getting errors on these lines: For some reason I cannot figure out the problem or what to do in order to fix it. I would greatly appreciate any help I can get and thanks in advance

```
Set rs = cn.Execute(sql),
ListBox1.AddItem (rs.Fields(0).Value) \srs.MoveNext()
```

And where it says .Open

On the .Open portion, the error I am getting is: run-time error '-214767259(800004005)': Invalid Argument

This is the only error I can see currently as it comes first but the other 2 lines above were giving errors to me before and unfortunately VBA only tells you the first error that stops the code.

```
Private Sub Browse_Click()
Dim fd As FileDialog, result As FileDialog, it As 

Variant
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
'FileDialog properties. initialfilename chooses the dialogbox start folder.
fd.Title = "Select a file,"
fd.Title = "Select a file"
fd.InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path
'You can Add filters over here fd.Filters.Clear
fd.Filters.Add "All files", "*.*"
If fd.Show = -1 Then
Debug.Print fd.SelectedItems(1)
End If
'selected filename is saved in fname parameter for later use. Also the same value is displayed on textbox
fname = fd.SelectedItems.Item(1)
TextBox1.Value = fname
End Sub
'This button will filter the data from database with the sql query and display it on the listbox
'Here the datasource is choosen the filw which is selected by the browse button and it has the sales order database
Private Sub RunQuery_Click()
Dim cn As Object, rs As Object, output As String, sql As String
'Connecting to the Data Source
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With cn
.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & fname & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
.Open
End With
'sql query to fetch order date from sales order database and the result will be stored on rs (resultset)
sql = "SELECT ProductName FROM Products where CategoryID=1"
Set rs = cn.Execute(sql)
' the result will be moved to listbox
If (rs.RecordCount <> 0) Then
Do While Not rs.EOF
ListBox1.AddItem (rs.Fields(0).Value) \ srs.MoveNext()
Loop
End If
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim fname As String
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for the help any is much appreciated!

Comment: @KenWhite I just did I hope that clears things up and if not please let me know what else I can add as it is my first time using stack overflow and I am unfamiliar with how everything works.

Comment: Your edit makes it much better. Thanks!

Comment: `sql = "SELECT ProductName FROM [Products$] where CategoryID=1"`. Also `\ srs.MoveNext()` cut paste error ??

Comment: @CDP1802 what do you mean cut paste error?

Comment: what is `\ srs.MoveNext()` ?

Comment: @CDP1802 when I did research on how to write it and what to write that is what it told me but I am unsure what it even means to be honest

Comment: Put the `rs.MoveNext()` on a new line and delete the \ s

Comment: @CDP1802 when I do that though it gives me an error stating: Compile error: Syntax error highlighting rs.MoveNext( )

Comment: Sorry , remove the brackets `rs.MoveNext`

Comment: @CDP1802 now I am getting a run-time error '-214767259(800004005)': Invalid Argument on the line .Open

Comment: I'd feel silly putting this as the answer... ListBox1.AddItem (rs.Fields(0).Value) \ srs.MoveNext() should be 2 lines, and it should be ListBox1.AddItem (rs.Fields(0).Value) rs.MoveNext()

Answer (score 0):

Test you are opening a valid workbook with this code :

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim fname As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Title = "Select a file,"
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path
        .Filters.Add "All files", "*.*"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            fname = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
        End If
    End With
    
    Dim cn As Object, rs As Object, sql As String
    'Connecting to the Data Source
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & fname & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES"";"
        .Open
    End With
    
    'sql query to fetch order date from sales order database
    'and the result will be stored on rs (resultset)
    sql = "SELECT ProductName FROM [Products$] WHERE CategoryID = 1"
    Set rs = cn.Execute(sql)
    MsgBox rs.GetString

End Sub
```